# Array of variables declared as string

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a query regarding creating an array of variables declared as string.
Below is my code. On debugging, the variables show no value.

Need help..

```
Module Module1

Public Status, PartStat, HomeStat, ClampStat, SldCylStat, PrsCylP1Stat, 
PrsCylP2Stat, PrsCylP3Stat, PrsCylP4Stat, PunchStat, SysInProc, Home1, 
Home2, Home3, CyclTim, TrqP1Stat, TrqP2Stat, TrqP3Stat, TrqP4Stat, 
AngleP1Stat, AngleP2Stat, AngleP3Stat, AngleP4Stat As String

Function AutoReadStatus()

    Dim StatArray = {HomeStat, ClampStat, SldCylStat, Home1, PrsCylP4Stat, 
    PrsCylP2Stat, Home2, PrsCylP3Stat, PrsCylP1Stat, Home3, PunchStat, 
    AngleP4Stat, AngleP2Stat, AngleP3Stat, AngleP1Stat, TrqP4Stat, 
    TrqP2Stat, TrqP3Stat, TrqP1Stat}

    Status = ReadMultiReg(FormAuto.SP1, "03", "1258", "0013")

    For i = 0 To ((Status.Length / 4) - 1)
        StatArray(i) = CInt("&H" & Status.Substring(i * 4, 4))
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
End Module
```

It is not even showing the index of any variable from above array..

```
Label1.Text = Array.IndexOf(StatArray, SldCylStat)
```

Comment: First, use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.100).aspx). It is best to also set it as the default for new projects. Once you have corrected any problems it points out, you may have a working program.

Comment: AutoReadStatus should be a `Sub` instead of a `Function` if you don't (want to) return a value

Comment: @ Andrew Morton, tried setting Option Strict On. It is not working though..

Comment: @Prashant setting Option Strict On is not meant to solve your problem, rather avoid other problems by enforcing a more robust **general** programming (for example the int -> string or int <-> double casts implicitely present in your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a new value to the item inside the array, you assign a **new value** to the item inside the array (pun intended).

What that means is that item's array now reference the string (or rather the Integer implicitely converted to string as you don't have Option Strict On) you gave and the precedent reference (on your public field) is dropped.

Test this sample code and I think you will understand

```
Public item As String

Sub Test()
    Dim array = {item}

    Console.WriteLine(array(0) Is item) ' True

    array(0) = "new value"

    Console.WriteLine(array(0) Is item) ' False
End Sub
```

You can see now `array(0)` reference another object than the one referenced by the `item` field

As for how to solve it,yYou could pass all those string `ByRef` that way assignment inside the method would reflect outside of it but that would be tedious.
A "better" way IMO, would be to make a type (a `Class`) to hold all those string and pass an instance of that type to your method, that way you just mutate the same existing object.

Quick, contrived example :

```
Class SomeType
    Property Item As String
End Class

Sub Test(instance As SomeType)
    instance.Item = "new value"
End Sub

' Usage
Dim sample As New SomeType
' here sample.Item is Nothing

Test(sample)
' here sample.Item is "new value"
```